# AHK: Remove duplicates from list, and add duplicate-count to respective list items

Tags: autohotkey

I would like an AutoHotkey code that will remove duplicates from a list, while also adding a duplicate-count to respective list items, i.e. “x 2.”

Here is an example list:

```
myList =
)
apple
banana
apple
apple pie
banana
apple
)
```

Here is the desired result list:

```
myList =
(
apple x 3
banana x 2
apple pie
)
```

I am a novice in AHK, and code in general.  I found many good codes for removing duplicates, but none to count them as indicated above.  My own approach to the solution may be rather rudimentary: it is to place unique items (“apple pie” above) into a variable, place duplicate items (all instances of “banana, apple”) into a separate variable, count/condense the like duplicates, and then combine the two variables together for the “desired result list.”  However, my own code will not work properly due to problems with substrings.  Rather than dilute this question with my code, it may be best to start with a more experienced, concise approach.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
MsgBox % CountList( MyList )

CountList( _list ) {
    l := StrSplit(_list,"`n"), out:="`n"
    for i, a in l {
        c:=0
        for j, b in l
            c := (a = b) ? c + 1 : c                
        if !(InStr(out, "`n" a "`t"))
            out .= a (c > 1 ? "`t x " c "`n" : "`n")
    }
    return Trim(out, "`n")
}
```

Comment: This is a great, concise code, nearly just what I’m looking for; thank you.  The code seems to add a "tab" before the duplicate count, i.e. "apple      x 2" instead of "apple x 2."  Could you alter the code in order to remove the tab from the result?

Comment: Note, the website removed "tab" from my comment above.  To clarify: tab = [ ]; The result I am looking for is "apple x 2" not "apple [ ] x 2"